# Flash not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 in my system with gnome shell.

When I try to watch any videos on any video streaming website in Firefox, I am not able to watch. At the same time those videos can be played in Chromium browser.

I have already installed Flash 11 and the Flash plugin for Firefox as well.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling them and installing again with synaptics =) ps sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue before. Try to remove flash first by running the following command in a terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get purge adobe-flashplugin
```

Then try to reinstall flash with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

That worked for me.

Comment: For me `flashflugin-nonfree` has not worked.  Reinstalling that has worked. `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

Answer (score 4):

Try to install the Firefox Add-On Flash-Aid, that Add-On will configure Flash for your system. You can easily choose between stable and beta version.

Comment: The solution suggested by remi was in my case the one that worked. Although choosing neither "beta flash" nor "stable flash" version but the option "install chrome flash"

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. This is how I was able to resolve it.

1. Go to the Firefox add-ons screen, ► Tools ► Add-ons ► Search for flash-aid then install it.
2. Restart Firefox.
3. In Firefox go to ► Tools ►  Flashaid ►  Quick Mode - Install beta flash
4. Restart the browser.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 10.10

If you are getting flash videos not showing from Youtube or other sites in **Firefox 11**, But you are in chrome Chrome.

And when you go to Youtube, you just get a black screen, folow these steps:

1. Go to  ►Tools ►Add Ons
2. Look for a PlugIn installed for **Shockwave Flash**, and disable that. Then Flash should start working okay from Youtube and other sites.

This may help anyone else having the problem with Firefox 11,  I wanted to post this in case it helped anyone else having problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling **Flash** using the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My fix was to remove Gnash and Gnash browser plugin. 
Gnash is a SWF standalone player/ browser plugin

Once removed try restarting firefox and all should be good.

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 11.10. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is using a build in flash plugin, whereas firefox is using the system wide. There are some problems with the new version, the 11.2 one. What I did was this (in a terminal):

1. Downloaded: `wget http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1-0natty1_i386.deb`
2. Installed it with `sudo dpkg -i adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1-0natty1_i386.deb'
3. And opened `sudo synaptic` to force the version.
   [image: synaptic]

This will do the trick. OR

1. Download http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1.orig.tar.gz
2. Copy the `libflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/`

   - To install it for a single user, put it in `~/.mozilla/plugins/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when or how gnash was installed on my machine, but using:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnash
```

sorted my problem out just fine (on 11.04, and presumably other versions).  Now I can watch iplayer again.

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar problem with myspace. However, it was not exactly flash nor firefox problem but certificates issue. 
Try following:

1. Go here: [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/support/intermediate/organizationssl_intermediate.php). Choose w OrganizationalSSL Intermediate. Copy the certificate in text editor (like gedit) and save it on hard disk for example: as FIX.CRT
2. Open Firefox: Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Encryption > Show certificates > Import > choose your certificate: FIX.CRT. Check the checkboxes.
3. Restart Firefox.